# What is the complete bare minimum space needed for Win 10 install

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

I installed Windows 10 on a virtual machine because, well, why not. I had to put the .vdi file on an external hard drive because apparently Win 10 64-bit needs 20Gb to install and run.

When I had the system fully installed on an 80Gb VirtualBox vdi, I looked in Computer and it said "69.5Gb used of 79.5Gb". The other 0.5Gb was recovery.

So I was using 10.5Gb instead of the advertised 20Gb. **My question is if it's safe to put the VDI on a 16Gb USB drive (obviously resized instead of 80Gb), and if there is any reason for the large difference.**

Any clarification appreciated!

Comment: What you can do is experiment for real. Make the VDI 16GB (or just under to make sure you can copy the whole VDI file into your USB) - and then install Windows 10 into that and see how you go (after updates etc). If you are running out of space - then that answers your question. Edit: Make sure you format your USB accordingly as FAT32 USB can't handle file size bigger than 4GB per file.

Comment: The problem you will run into is that eventually the VM will grow to beyond 16GB even though it literally needs less space when that happens you'll get errors with the virtualization software before you actually run out of space.  If that statement makes any sense...

Answer (score -1):

From my experience Windows updates and application installs make the c:\Windows\WinSxS folder grow quite large over time. It will consume your entire 16GB USB drive eventually.

I setup a Windows 8 Micro PC with a 32 GB drive and it was almost full after installing AV software and all the windows updates. Upgrading to Windows 10 gave me more space, but it still wasn't a lot of free space.

Comment: Windows 8 was unique in that it had a feature and could be specifically targeted to extremely limited storage devices.  Windows 10 does not have this feature

Comment: @Ramhound I've heard of this feature somewhere... I think its called something like CompactOS.EXE, but I may be wrong

Comment: Windows 10 has the feature interestingly enough - but not enabled by default. There is an article here http://www.anandtech.com/show/9676/windows-10-feature-focus-compactos that describe what you can try / test. Simply running `compact.exe /CompactOS:Query` to see if it is enabled or not, and you can enable it by `compact.exe /CompactOS:Always` and see how you go.